# Learning material on optical computing

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, education, photonics

I'm looking for guidance to choose material for a self-study of [photonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photonics), biased towards [optical computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_computing) recent advances.

My background is of undergraduate level electrodynamics, quantum mechanics, statistical mechanics, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have some experience with information theory as it relates to computation theory.  This book:

http://books.google.com/books/about/Optical_computing.html?id=ZfFRAAAAMAAJ

is a good foundational look at how optical computing works, combining the physical processes with the computational understanding.

This paper will provide a more up-to-date overview of where the state of optical computing is today: http://www.hindawi.com/journals/aot/2010/372652/ and more importantly provide further direction on where to look for more information.